# update expression in for loop is not compiling

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

Why the following loop is not compiling

```
for(int i=1,j=3;i<3; while(j-->=0) {System.out.println(j);},i++  );
```

It because java not allow any other statement other than increment in update expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OP is trying to do is actually possible. The thing is, *increment expression* can be only a single expression. It doesn't have to be incrementation. It can be any expression. Following code compiles:

```
private static void innerLoop(int i, int j){
    while(j-->=0) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    for(int i=1,j=3;i<3;innerLoop(i++,j));
}
```

**EDIT**
Now, the "single expression" term is not as plain and simple as I thought, as it is possible to compile following code as well:

```
private static void innerLoop(int j){
    while(j-->=0) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

...

```
for(int i=1,j=3;i<3;innerLoop(j), i++);
```

After further reading, I guess that *increment expression* just cannot have a direct [control flow statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html). Avoiding control flow statements by hiding them inside functions works just fine.

Comment: "It can be any expression, as long as it's single expression." is quite confusing. Lets stay we have `for (int i=0, j=10; i<j; i++,j--)`. Do you consider `i++,j--` part *single* expression?

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong syntax `for(int i=1,j=3;i<3; while(j-->=0)`.
`for` loop is a different looping mechanism, and `while` also you can consider as its counterpart.

But `while` instead of the *increment* part in `for` wont even compile.

Try doing this :-

```
for(int i = 1, j = 3; i < 3 && j-- >= 0; i++) {
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

*OR*

```
while(j>=0){ // whatever your condition
 System.out.println(j); //your logic here
 j--; // increment/decrement
}
```

Find the official doc of `for`  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and `while` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: `(int i = 1, j = 3; i < 3 && j-- >= 0, i++)` - here an error

Comment: @AndrewTobilko typo . fixed it to :- `for(int i = 1, j = 3; i < 3 && j-- >= 0; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1, j = 3; i < 3 && j-- >= 0; i++) {
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Did you like it?

> The basic `for` statement executes some initialization code, then executes an `Expression`, a `Statement`, and some update code repeatedly until the value of the `Expression` is false.
>
> Basic `for` Statement:
>
> `for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement`

Answer (score 0):

as per the oracle docs

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:

The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

The 3rd parameter should be an increment/decrment value

Comment: Third parameter can by **any** expression.

Comment: @talex what do you mean by any expression?

Comment: I mean `for(;;((Type1)foo().bar(baz?a1:a2)).aaa.doit());` is perfectly legal for statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntx for the for loop, you cannot write it like that.

#### First the initialisation:

`i = 1, j = 3`

#### Then comes the condition:

`i < 3 && j >= 0`

#### Then comes the inc/dec or Updating the variables:

`i++, j--`

```
for(int i=1, j=3; i<3 && j >=0; i++, j--)
{
System.out.println(j);
}
```

Comment: `=  *=  /=  %=  +=  -=  <<=  >>=  >>>=  &=  ^=  |=` and `++i, i++, --i, i--` in third part of statement

Comment: I was just referring to the code, There can be many more valid statements.